# Add dot after number of listing in list of listings

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, tocloft, renewcommand

Hello does some of you know how to add leading dot after listing number in list of listings?

Im using `listings` package and `\lstlistoflistings` command.

Im using `tocloft` package to do it in list of figures but I think its not doable with this package.

Here's example where I would love dots to be:
[image: list of listings example]

I can also provide MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, polish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{polski}

% Listing package and customization
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{background}{RGB}{40,42,54}
\definecolor{foreground}{RGB}{248,248,242}
\lstdefinestyle{syntaxStyle}{
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    columns=flexible,
    captionpos=t,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=true,                  
    tabsize=2,
    xleftmargin=.15\textwidth,
    xrightmargin=.15\textwidth,
    aboveskip=.7cm,
    belowskip=.7cm
}

\lstset{
  frame=lines,
  style=syntaxStyle
}

\begin{document}

% Test Listings
\begin{lstlisting}[language = Java, caption={This is some title}]
// This is test of listing
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language = Java, caption={This is some title}]
// This is test of listing
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language = Java, caption={This is some title}]
// This is test of listing
}
\end{lstlisting}

% List of listings
Here's list of listings
\lstlistoflistings
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks! MWE added :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a patch to the command adding the listing to the list of listing.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\lst@MakeCaption{\protect\numberline{\thelstlisting}\lst@@caption}{\protect\numberline{\thelstlisting.}\lst@@caption}{}{}
\makeatother
```

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, polish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{polski}

% Listing package and customization
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{background}{RGB}{40,42,54}
\definecolor{foreground}{RGB}{248,248,242}
\lstdefinestyle{syntaxStyle}{
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    columns=flexible,
    captionpos=t,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=true,                  
    tabsize=2,
    xleftmargin=.15\textwidth,
    xrightmargin=.15\textwidth,
    aboveskip=.7cm,
    belowskip=.7cm
}

\lstset{
    frame=lines,
    style=syntaxStyle
}


% <<<<<<<<<<<< added
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\lst@MakeCaption{\protect\numberline{\thelstlisting}\lst@@caption}{\protect\numberline{\thelstlisting.}\lst@@caption}{}{}
\makeatother
% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
% Test Listings
\begin{lstlisting}[language = Java, caption={This is some title}]
// This is test of listing
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language = Java, caption={This is some title}]
// This is test of listing
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language = Java, caption={This is some title}]
// This is test of listing
}
\end{lstlisting}

% List of listings
Here's list of listings
\lstlistoflistings
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works amazingly well!